# Why can the Xbox360 not detect the Arduino Leonardo as keyboard?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, teensy, keyboard, hid

Arduino Leonardo as keyboard in the computer works! But not with the Xbox360.
The Teensy works perfectly on the PC but how to emulate a keyboard device for the Xbox360.

I know the Xbox360 has security IC, but a simple USB keyboard works!

What is the diference ?

How i can emulate an usb keyboard for the Xbox360?

Comment: It probably needs the "Boot Keyboard" protocol, which the Leonardo doesn't provide.

Comment: I very new to hid devices, i will find out about that

Comment: does leonardo work as a keyboard at boot time in BIOS?

Comment: i don't remember, i guess no, but i will try later!

Comment: @jsotola, it doesn't work as boot keyboard with Arduino Keyboard library. this library can emulate boot keyboard on Leonardo: https://github.com/NicoHood/HID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Juraj and Majenko said. Arduino Keyboard library does emulate "Boot Keyboard".

I use [NicoHood HID library](https://github.com/NicoHood/HID) and now it works.